# ASP classic select date BETWEEN dates on SQL Server

Tags: sql, date, between

I run the next query in my classic asp code and it run perfect. it returns results between the days "from" and "to"

```
query = 'SELECT DateAndTime, X, Y, Z FROM '+ Request.QueryString("table") + ' where DateAndTime between '+"'"+Request("from")+"'" +' and ' +"'"+Request("to")+"'order by DateAndTime";
```

However,I cannot find out what is wrong with the next query:
I want it to return the results of the last week that are recorded in the database.

```
query = 'SELECT DateAndTime, X, Y, Z FROM '+ Request.QueryString("table") + ' where DateAndTime between DATEADD("d",-7,(select MAX(DateAndTime) from '+ Request.QueryString("table") + ')) and (select MAX(DateAndTime) from '+ Request.QueryString("table") + ') order by DateAndTime";
```

Any Ideas?
The query is ok when i run it on Microsoft SQL Server Management studio.
Maybe the problem is at the syntax?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html). **NEVER** use string concatenation to build a SQL query. **ALWAYS** use a parameterized query.

Comment: Your code is absolutely horrible.  So easy for someone to drop your database.

Comment: **NB:** You can't use a parameter to dynamically reference a table like that. Instead, you'll need to verify the querystring value against a known list of valid tables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggetion Richard. I am new to coding, so i would apreciate if you give me an example of a parameterized query to my situation. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a quotation mark before *order by DateAndTime*

```
query = 'SELECT DateAndTime, X, Y, Z FROM '+ Request.QueryString("table") + ' where DateAndTime between DATEADD("d",-7,(select MAX(DateAndTime) from '+ Request.QueryString("table") + ')) and (select MAX(DateAndTime) from '+ Request.QueryString("table") + ') "order by DateAndTime";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but it still doesnt work...

Comment: i will accept your answer beacause you opened my eyes. However the right is that i should close the query with  '  before semicolon and not " . I didnt have to add the " you proposed. Thanks anyway!